# How to unhide hidden applications in application menu

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, 23.10

When you right-click an application in the application menu, there is an option to hide the app icon from the application menu (but not to delete it). Now how do I unhide the icon? As far as I know, the "Hide" feature is not a part of GNOME and surely is an extension, but there is no installed extension visible in the extension manager that does that.

Comment: I have provided an answer for an extension that provides a *Hide* option, but we cannot be sure that this is actually the extension you have installed without more info. Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -1 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 23.10, which comes with GNOME 45 installed, does not have by default a *Hide* option in the right-click menu of an application. An extension that provides this option, however, is [App Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5895/app-hider/).

If you indeed have the App Hider extension installed and enabled, then according to the [extension's GitHub page](https://github.com/LynithDev/gnome-app-hider#usage):

> To unhide an app, go to the extension's options and remove any entries from the list.